# Javascript/Node JS - Azure Functions, Key Vault & Document DB - connect EAccess Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am using Document/Cosmos DB and Key Vault from an Azure Function and at times I get the following error :

```
Error: connect EACCES XX.XXX.XX.XX:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
        at connect (net.js:875:16)
        at net.js:1004:7
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10)
```

The error happens when connecting to Key Vault and/or Document DB and after many successful connections to the same Key Vault/Document DB. What are possible causes and solutions for this type of error?

Comment: Can you provide the Azure Functions config and code?

Comment: This error generally indicates a case of connections exhaustion. Sharing function code will help investigate this further. If you are running on consumption plan, it might help if you move to App Service Plan.

Comment: @PragnaGopa Yes, error seems to be related to http connection exhaustion. Any idea if this http exhaustion is due to limits set in the node js process or the app service plan /instance? I am not using consumption plan. Increasing the number of instances or scaling-out helps to a certain degree.

Comment: Very likely you are hitting limits imposed by [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). Try monitoring with [AppInsights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/azure-functions-now-integrated-with-application-insights/) this should have more detailed errors.